# forward DependencyProperty to control contained in User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, wpf-controls

I'm trying to make a user control that has a few `DependencyProperties` which are forward to child controls in the user control. After a few trys I got this to work. For testing a made a small example.

In the example I have a user control named `Ctrl` that just contains a `TextBox` and exposes the `Text` property of the `TextBox`. This control is used in a window which contains a `TextBox` and my custom `Ctrl` which are bound to the same property.

#### user control

XAML

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="trying.Ctrl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
    Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyText}" />
</UserControl>
```

Code behind

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace trying
{
    public partial class Ctrl : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MyText",
            typeof( string ),
            typeof( UserControl ),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( default(string), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
        public string MyText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue( MyTextProperty ); }
            set { SetValue( MyTextProperty, value ); }
        }

        public Ctrl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

#### window

XAML

```xml
<Window x:Class="trying.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:trying"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding DisplayText}" />
        <cc:Ctrl Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MyText="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DisplayText}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

code behind

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace trying
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged( string propertyName )
        {
            if( PropertyChanged != null )
                PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
        }

        private string m_displayText = "asdf";
        public string DisplayText
        {
            get { return m_displayText; }
            set
            {
                m_displayText = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged( "DisplayText" );
            }
        }

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

#### problem

How I posted the code it works. My question is now: What have I done wrong that I have to use the binding

```xml
 MyText="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}
```

When binding the `MyText` property of `Ctrl` and can not just the simple binding like I use when binding the original `TextBox`?

If I don't bind this way it won't work, and I get the warning

```
  System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error: 'DisplayText' property
  not found on 'object' ''Ctrl' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=DisplayText; 
  DataItem='Ctrl' (Name=''); target element is 'Ctrl' (Name=''); target property
  is 'MyText' (type 'String')
```

What do I have to change that binding is possible like with the original `TextBox`?

during execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UserControl`'s `DataContext` is pointing to itself, so any binding on an instance of the control will be looking at the `Ctrl` instance rather than the inherited `DataContext`.

Try setting the `DataContext` further down the tree:

```
<UserControl 
   x:Class="trying.Ctrl" x:Name="root"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
>
   <TextBox 
      DataContext="{Binding ElementName=root}"
      Text="{Binding MyText}" 
   />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is this thinking correct: Since the Binding is a 'content' of `Ctrl` it gets evaluated in it's context. Therefore, as you said, the local `DataContext` applies. If I had e.g. a `Grid` inside `Ctrl` I could set the `DataContext` on this `Grid`, since the Binding occurs in the `UserControl` in `Ctrl`. My way of setting the `DataContext` should only be used for `Window`s etc. not for `UserControl`s

Comment: Yes, if you set the `DataContext` on the `Grid`, bindings on the `UserControl` would use the inherited `DataContext`, and bindings on the `Grid` or any child of the `Grid` would use the new `DataContext`.